# Jackson deserialization to subclass with optional parameter

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a question about jackson deserialization, for example we have a parent class foo and subclass bar:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.Name, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
property = "bar", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes( { 
  @Type(value = Foo.class, bar = ""),
  @Type(value = Bar.class, bar = "true")
})
public class Foo{ String value; }

public class Bar extends Foo { boolean bar; }
```

subclass comes in json format as:

```
{ 
"value": "this is some value for bar class",
"bar": "true"
}
```

but I need jackson to deserialize foo class as well, and it should identify by that boolean value in the child class. Because request might come in as

```
{ "value": "this is some foo class value" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that will be useful to someone.

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.Name, 
      // this will ignore boolean bar value in the parent
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "bar",
      // this will make a default implementation
        defaultImpl = Foo.class)
    @JsonSubTypes( {@Type(value = Bar.class, name = "true") })
    public class Foo{ String value; }

    public class Bar extends Foo { boolean bar; }
```